# Finding location of elements w.r.t original matrix after reshape in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 1*262144 matrix which I have reshaped into a 512*512 matrix. Now, I need certain elements from my 2nd matrix and want to know their location as it was in the original row matrix. Say, i need element which is at (256,4) in my reshaped matrix. How can I know the position of this element in my original row only matrix?

```
 matri_working_now = C(1,:);
    matrix_working_now = reshape(matri_working_now,512,512);
    [nrows,ncols] = size(matrix_stables);   %matrix_stables is a matrix over which I am looping over which contains the locations of the desired elements as per the reshaped matrix. this itself is a 30839*2 matrix
    for row = 1:nrows
        for col = 1:ncols
        %sub2ind(size(matrix_working_now),row,col)
        %fprintf('iteration is equal to %6.2f.\n',row,col);
        [rowss colum] = ind2sub(size(matri_working_now),sub2ind(size(matrix_working_now),matrix_stable(row),matrix_stable(col)));    % i am accessing the elements of matrix_stables which provide me the row and column numbers; 

        end
    end
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your original matrix is a vector, you only need to [convert from subindices to linear index](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), with [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
col = sub2ind(size(reshapedMatrix), 256,4);
```

In general, if the original matrix is not necessarily a vector, you need a second step with [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[row col] = ind2sub(size(originalMatrix), sub2ind(size(reshapedMatrix), 256,4));
```

*Example:*

```
>> originalMatrix = (1:10).^2
originalMatrix =
     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100

>> reshapedMatrix = reshape(originalMatrix, 2,5)
reshapedMatrix =
     1     9    25    49    81
     4    16    36    64   100

>> reshapedMatrix(2,3)
ans =
    36

>> [row col] = ind2sub(size(originalMatrix), sub2ind(size(reshapedMatrix), 2,3))
row =
     1
col =
     6

>> originalMatrix(row,col)
ans =
    36
```

Comment: i get the "out of range subscript error"; i am reposting my full code for better viewing.

Comment: Please see the edited code in the original post .Thanks!

Comment: @KashifNawaz In your `sub2ind` line, I think you have the sizes interchanged. Compare with my answer

Comment: Same error again! the matri_ is my original matrix; matrix_ is my reshaped matrix. Else, I did not get your point otherwise.

Comment: Please see edited code above. Now got the error Undefined function 'matrix_stable' for input arguments of type 'double'.i think i have to use mat2something for this change, which one do you think?

Comment: The edition is the part matrix_stable(row),matrix_stable(col) which is  for your (2,3) in your example

Comment: basically I am using the elements of the matrix_stable matrix as row and col inputs to the sub2ind function

Comment: [rowss colum] = ind2sub(size(matri_working_now),sub2ind(size(matrix_working_now),458,6));   the 458 and 6 values have been manually given. I would like these values to be read out from another matrix. How would I do that?

Comment: please provide your assistance w.r.t above comment